# search list for keywords in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, search, filter

I have an input (search) and a multi select list.
The select list is to be "quick searchable".
The input from the search box will likely be space delimited. EX: "thing im looking for"
I want the only selectable options to contain ALL keywords.
I have tried 100 permutations of filter and map, and can not seem to make this happen. Thanks in advance for any and all help.

The following is the general gist of what I am working with.

```
this.state = {
    search:["some terms"],
    list:["terms A some","some B terms", "C some term"]
}

renderOptions = (list, search) => {
    let options
    search.forEach(term =>{
      options = term.length > 0 ? list.filter(list => list.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())) : options
    })
    return options && options.map((option,i)=>
      <option key={i} value={option}>{option}</option>
    )
  }

handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.value.toLowerCase().split(' ')})
}

render(){
    ...
    <Form.Control name="search" type="text" placeholder="search terms" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
    <Form.Control as="select" multiple>
        { this.state.list && this.renderOptions(this.state.list,this.state.search) }
    </Form.Control>
}
```

The select list should find this.state.list[0] and [1] true, and [2] false

```
<select>
    <option> terms A some </option>
    <option> some B terms </option>
</select>
```

Comment: is using a third party libraries an option? select2 and boostrap-select are usually the defacto standard

Comment: @Deano Thanks for that suggestion, I will check it out, but I was hoping there was some simple React solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
const courses = [
  'Economics',
  'Math II',
  'Math I'
];

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      search: []
    }
  }

  render() {
    let options;
    if (this.state.search.length) {
      const searchPattern = new RegExp(this.state.search.map(term => `(?=.*${term})`).join(''), 'i');
      options = courses.filter(option => 
        option.match(searchPattern)
      );
    } else {
      options = courses;
    }
  
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e) => this.setState({search: e.target.value.split(' ')})}/>
        <ul>
            {options.map((option, i) => 
              <li key={option+i}>{option}</li>
            )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SearchBar />, document.body)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Courses does not appear to be defined and options is being set for each term overriding the previous. We can also simplify greatly by using case insensitive regexp for filter and match.

Comment: Within your example, searching for, "II Math" returns both Math II and Math I.

Comment: @mbunch Fixed by switching to positive lookahead regexp

Answer (score 0):

@mbunch, I have created the following example using `react-select` component, to help you provid cleaner front end code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/8y87l3ynll?fontsize=14

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to create the example, however, this does not meet my requirements.
Within the select list, the options should contain multiple words per option. "orange and banana", "kiwi and banana" etc.
Then when searching, you should be able to search for "banana orange" and only the one option with both keywords should be returned.