# Line 18:54: 'filteredYear' is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component from a udemy course I'm taking but it stopped working and I don't know why?

I get now

```
src/components/Expenses/Expenses.js
  Line 18:54:  'filteredYear' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

What does it mean "search for keywords"?

These are the results when I look that up and what it means by that

[search list for keywords in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54994248/search-list-for-keywords-in-react)

[How to filter or search an array of objects in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57861003/how-to-filter-or-search-an-array-of-objects-in-react)

It's not quite the same context?

Here my code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import Card from '../UI/Card'
import ExpenseItem from './ExpenseItem';
import ExpensesFilter from './ExpensesFilter';
import './Expenses.css';

function Expenses(props) {

  const [pickedYear, setPickedYear] = useState('2020')

  const selectedFilterYear = (filteredYear) => {
    console.log('the selected filtered year is: ' + filteredYear)
    setPickedYear(filteredYear);
  }

  const filteredExpenses = props.items.filter(expense => {
    return expense.date.getFullYear().toString() === filteredYear;
  });

  return(
    <div>
      <Card className="expenses">
        <ExpensesFilter selected={pickedYear} onFilterYear={selectedFilterYear} />
        {filteredExpenses.map(expense => 
          <ExpenseItem
            key={expense.id}
            title={expense.title} 
            amount={expense.amount} 
            date={expense.date} 
          />
        )}
      </Card>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Expenses;
```

How do you go about fixing this? Is there another context I need to look for? Can you not use an argument or something? Very confused here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have a typo: you name your state variable `pickedYear` but seems you refer to it later as `filteredYear`.

> As for the "search for the keywords" message, this is coming from [eslint](https://eslint.org/). Eslint uses "keywords" for all of its rules. The eslint rule that is being triggered is
>
> - `no-undef`
>
> Searching for this shows the relevant eslint docs on this specific rule (https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef), but you probably don't need the full docs to show what the issue is since this rule is more straight forward that some of eslint's other rules.

The error message is telling you exactly what it says: that `filteredYear` on line 18 is not defined. The only place you have `filteredYear` defined is *within* your `selectedFilterYear` function, which defines that as the only argument it accepts.

To fix this, just use the same state variable you've already set:

```js
// Here you name your piece of state `pickedYear`
const [pickedYear, setPickedYear] = useState('2020');

const filteredExpenses = props.items.filter(expense => {
    // So refer to that same `pickedYear` variable here 
    return expense.date.getFullYear().toString() === pickedYear;
});
```